# Automatically show a bootstrap-datetimepicker on creation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have a [datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), which I want to automatically open as soon as it has been created.  I've tried calling the `show` method after creation, which works, but then it won't close afterwards!

For example, I intuitively expect that the widget would close when I click outside, or when it loses focus.

```js
// Set up form widgets
$("#input_completed_at").datetimepicker({
  sideBySide: true
});

$("#input_completed_at").data("DateTimePicker").show();
```

```css
.modal-open .modal.modal-allow-overflow {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="myModal" class='modal fade modal-allow-overflow' data-width="760">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Pick a date!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="input_completed_at">Task Completion Date</label>
          <div class="input-group date" id="input_completed_at">
            <input type="text" name="completed_at" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a better approach to get it to show automatically, but then close automatically when it loses focus/click outside?

UPDATE: It seems to only be a problem when my datepicker is inside a Bootstrap modal popup.  See the updated example.

Comment: Try the `autoclose:true` property in your env.

Comment: @Vijai, are you sure you're not thinking of the [bootstrap datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker)?  I'm looking for help with the [datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) by eonasdan.

Comment: Working fine for me

Comment: @NooBskie try clicking inside the modal, but outside of the field itself.

Comment: Ahhh so you want it to close when clicking in the modal correct?

Comment: Exactly, that is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [bootstrap modal events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) like `shown.bs.modal` to show the datetimepicker when the modal is shown.

Here a live example:

```js
// Set up form widgets
$("#input_completed_at").datetimepicker({
  sideBySide: true
});

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $("#input_completed_at").data("DateTimePicker").show();
});
```

```css
.modal-open .modal.modal-allow-overflow {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="myModal" class='modal fade modal-allow-overflow' data-width="760">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Pick a date!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="input_completed_at">Task Completion Date</label>
          <div class="input-group date" id="input_completed_at">
            <input type="text" name="completed_at" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great - but can you explain why?  My guess is that by holding the `show()` method on the datetimepicker until the parent modal itself is rendered, I am avoiding some kind of layering/z-index issue.  Does this sound correct?

Comment: I don't think z-index is an issue here, but probably the datetimepicker has problem when is attached to non visible elements. Anyway I think that opening the picker after that the parent modal itself is rendered it's more "natural" solution and fortunately it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky but seems to be working for me

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script> <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">   Launch demo modal </button>

<div id="myModal" class='modal fade modal-allow-overflow' data-width="760">   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Pick a date!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="input_completed_at">Task Completion Date</label>
          <div class="input-group date" id="input_completed_at">
            <input type="text" name="completed_at" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>   </div> </div>
```

**JS**

```
// Set up form widgets
$("#input_completed_at").datetimepicker({
  sideBySide: true
});

$("#input_completed_at").data("DateTimePicker").show();
$( ".modal-header" ).click(function() {
  $("#input_completed_at").data("DateTimePicker").hide();
});

$( "#input_completed_at" ).click(function() {
  $("#input_completed_at").data("DateTimePicker").toggle();
});
```

**EDIT**
If you want it to open on modal init you can bind a click to the button instead

```
$( ".btn" ).click(function() {
  $("#input_completed_at").data("DateTimePicker").show();
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/ozNGBz)